# Serialise msg object coming from Kafka Producer and store in influxdb in Node-Red flow

Tags: apache-kafka, influxdb, node-red

I have the flow below in node-red, I need the msg object to be stored in influxdb -
[image]

As you can see in the debug node coming out of the kafka consumer, the payload is being stored in Influxdb as [object Object] and not in a serialised manner with each column separated. If I store the msg object directly into influxdb(without the kafka producer and consumer in-between), then it's stored in db as required.

Is there a way to store the msg object in the influxdb properly with the kafka producer and consumer being part of the flow?

Comment: Have you tried including a JSON node before the kafka producer node?

Comment: Yes, thank you introducing json node worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As worked out in the comments, you need to include a JSON node before the Kafka Producer node because it expects a String as input not a JavaScript Object and the JSON node will Serialise the Object to a JSON string.